# checking in code to Visual SVN server using Tortoise svn client

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

Does anyone know how to check in the code to Visual svn server using Tortoise svn client??

I tried to access the repo browser url through tortoise and it is giving me "Could not connect to the server" error.

Is it necessary that i should have Visual svn server installed on my machine for this??

Thanks
Sneha

Comment: There are not such term as "check in" in Subversion. There are "checkout" and "commit"

Comment: If you can't reach server on commit, can you use any other svn-commands with repo URL without errors? Is your URL correct?

Comment: by check in i meant Commit. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to have Visual SVN server installed. Have you checked the URL? Can it be that you have firewall that is blocking Tortoise SVN client? Without more details I can only keep guessing.

Comment: you mean the proxy is blocking??

Comment: Proxies do not block anything. I mean firewall - either local one (like Windows firewall) or your company one.

Answer (score 0):

Check the URL with a web browser to ensure that you can connect.  You do not need to have (nor should you have) the server software running locally.